# Pi Crashing - NTP Issue ?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I am running a Raspberry Pi 3 as a weather station at home, and it will crash every couple of days.   When I restart, the only clue in syslog is:

```
Apr 15 13:35:27 weather systemd[642]: Time has been changed
Apr 15 13:35:27 weather ntpd[471]: receive: Unexpected origin timestamp 0xde7ce04f.465baf92 does not match aorg 0000000000.00000000 from server@46.227.200.74 xmt 0xde7dc58f.70ff4546
```

/etc/ntp.conf is pointing to pool.ntp.org.

The server has a static IP address on an internal LAN.

Perplexed.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: The joys of systemd?   Will you have some Poettering with that?  https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1143

Comment: Kernel patching?  Eek!  I thought I'd left that behind when I shut down my last Slack server!

Comment: I just wanted to point out that systemd has had problems with time changes before.  Perhaps use another pool?

Comment: I have an ESXi host and a dozen VMs on the same network (and they have kept time flawlessly for two years). I might point it at one of them..

Comment: Would you trust an ESXi with something as precious as time?  ;-)   Perhaps faelix.net should change to failix.net.   Are they part of an NTP pool?

Comment: Was really thinking of using one of my CentOS VMs as an ntpd server. Point it at my ISP and hey presto, no?

Comment: Do use the ESXi.  When that one goes down, none of the VM's will complain, will they?  You'll need to run a time deamon, I suppose?

Comment: I don't really want to fiddle with the ESXi OS (Debian, I think?), as I might break it.  :-)

Comment: "apt-get install ntp"  and update (if necessary) /etc/ntp.conf?  Keep us informed, I'm curious if this will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, easy to get ntp up and running, done it before. The VMs are currently using the host for time sync but I have a test/dev db box that I'll switch to using ntpd and use that as upstream for my Pi.  Will let you know.  :-)

Comment: PS. my RPi was crashing because of the sandisk (or whatever). In your case, if the ntpd was the origin of the problem, would it still be logged?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76097/discussion-between-darren-matheson-and-gerard-h-pille).